# How to create a trace outline animation of an object

Tags: eevee-render-engine

I have a blender product animation, and I'd like to show animated tracing of the outline of an object, like this:

In the past I've seen this kinda stuff done in after effects. Can Blender 2.9 do [this](https://youtu.be/T2ablH1np5M?t=10)?

[image: trace 1]
[image: trace 2]
[image]

Comment: Quickly ... Import or create a few curves and and Build modifier https://vimeo.com/315949733

Answer (score 3):

General idea is to use **Build** modifier on *Curve* object.

---

If you have a model already, you can ...

- *Separate* <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd> a few loops into a new object
- *Convert to Curve*
- and Add *Build* modifier

[image]

[image]

Notes:

- If you want to let all curve elements be animated at the same time you have to split them into separate objects.
- Usually it is better to Separate mesh loops as lowpoly without Subdivision modifier, Convert to Curve, switch curve type to Bezier with Handles > Automatic and manually adjust few end handles, so you have better control over additional curve shape adjustment. But like in this case it was easier to apply Subsurf modifier on separated mesh before Convert to Curve.
- if you need more smooth animation increase curve resolution under Curve Properties

Based on [TheGreens](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OrGjJBdZx0c) model.

[image]